# bash printf - how to align text to right in the same line without deleting previous output

Tags: bash, debian

I'm trying to have in script `Done` or `Fail` statuses aligned to the right of previous text. But not e.g. 50 chars from last character, but 50 chars from left side of terminal. I'm not printing it using single, but multiple `printf`'s. In code I have e.g.

```
    printf "Creating folder..."
    sleep 2
    mkdir foo
    printf "\r%50.10s\n" "Done"
```

Unfortunately it keeps me outputting

```
                                                  Done
```

instead of

```
    Creating folder...                            Done
```

Is there a possibility to align text to right in the same line without deleting previous output?

Debian 8, bash 4.3.30

Comment: Note that the output is exactly what you requested; it is just that what you requested is not really what you wanted.  Blanks overwrite; they are not transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options, at least.

1. Simply extend what's already output:

   ```
   printf "Creating folder..."
   mkdir foo
   sleep 2
   printf "%32s\n" "Done"
   ```
2. Rewrite what was already output:

   ```
   printf "Creating folder..."
   mkdir foo
   sleep 2
   printf "\r%-50s %s\n" "Creating folder..." "Done"
   ```

I moved the `sleep` after the `mkdir` to give you some chance to read error messages from `mkdir` before the `printf` kicks in again.

You might want to think about showing the folder name in the messages too.

Comment: The second option is great. It answers me in way that I needed.
Oh, and that code is just an example, in real code I'm siliencing output by > /dev/null 2>&1 and sleep is for giving user chance to read what script will do and eventually to allow him for interrupting that action :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ANSI escape code to explicitly position the cursor in column 50:

```
printf "Creating folder..."
sleep 2
mkdir foo
printf "\033[50G%s\n" "Done"
        ^^^^^^^^
```

This does not require calculating a width based on how much was already printed or reprinting the first part of the line. It does assume a terminal that processes ANSI escape codes, though.